# adding a keyboard shortcut to your button in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shortcut, keyevent, keyup

I have a button that does something when clicking on it with mouse. I want the same method to also be triggered when pressing on your keyboard's up arrow key.

```
<button @click="doSomething()"> PRESS ME </button>

doSomething(){
  console.log('clicked')
}
```

So in this example I want to `console.log('clicked')` when pressing on keyboard's up arrow.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use [`onkeystroke` from `vueuse`](https://vueuse.org/core/onkeystroke/#onkeystroke)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="doSomething">btn</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onKeyStroke } from '@vueuse/core';

const doSomething = () => {
  console.log('do something');
}

onKeyStroke(['ArrowUp'], (e) => {
  doSomething();
});
</script>
```

[another demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-n2j6tc?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FExample.vue,src%2FApp.vue)

*`stackblitz.com` doesn't support `<script setup>` so in this demo, it is written in `setup()`*

---

update

pure js without library:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button
            @click="doSomething">
            btn
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue';

const doSomething = () => {
    console.log('doSomething');
};

const userClickArrowUp = ({ code }) => {
    if (code === 'ArrowUp') {
        doSomething();
    }
};

onMounted(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', userClickArrowUp, true);
})

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', userClickArrowUp, true);
})

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but is there another way to do it without using a library?

Comment: @seyet Yeap, see the update

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help you.

```js
doSomething(){
  console.log('clicked')
}

var buttonBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
buttonBtn.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.doSomething();
});
```

```html
<button id="btn" @click="doSomething()"> PRESS ME </button>
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants it to be a global shortcut, not just for a single element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as all click events and keyboard shortcuts:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click.ctrl="onClick">Ctrl + Click me</button>
    <button @click.alt="onClick">Alt + Click me</button>
    <button @click.ctrl.exact="onClick">Ctrl exact + Click me</button>
    <button @click.left="onClick">Left mouse button</button>
    <button @click.right="onClick">Right mouse button</button>
    <button @click.middle="onClick">Middle mouse button</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants it to be a global shortcut, not just for a single element.

Answer (score 0):

From [vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#key-modifiers)
better [examples](https://blog.boot.dev/javascript/vue-key-events/)

**I haven't found a vue solution that works global.** For those looking for component/html specific shortcuts

"When listening for keyboard events, we often need to check for
specific keys. Vue allows adding key modifiers for v-on or @ when
listening for key events:"

```
<input @keydown.up="onPressUp" />
```